# Rails 3: How to “redirect_to” in Ajax call when form submited using html

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax

I am using iframe for uploading files in rails 3.2, after submitting form using iframe how to redirect my page in "ajax" call

```
if @user.save
    format.html { redirect_to users_path }
    format.json { render json: @user, status: :created, location: @user }
    format.js { render :layout => false }
  end
```

I am tried using,

```
format.html { render js: "window.location.pathname = #{users_path.to_json}" }
```

Comment: If possible , please provide more details with code sample

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This works for me:

```
format.js {render js: "window.location = '#{users_path}';"}
```

Don't forget to quote `'` the url inside the js string, because in the code you pasted in your question you seem to have forgot them

Also use `users_path` and not `users_path.to_json`

Comment: It not redirect to users_path, it display simply like this window.location = '/users';

Comment: I submit form via **html** request, how can i redirect_to js @Benjamin

Comment: @Achu why would you submit it as **html** if you want a **js** response? in your form you could just pass `format: :js`. eg. `form_for(@user, format: :js)` will render the `js` portion.

Answer (score 1):

It can be

```
if @user.save
  format.html { redirect_to users_path }
  format.json { render json: @user, status: :created, location: @user }
  format.js { render js: "window.location = '#{users_url}';" }
end
```

so when it will ajax request it will automatically execute `format.js` and it will render

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use redirect_to(users_path) in your action in controller